# Сборка мусора в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

```
    auto data = new QPushBtnCoords(row, column);
    data->setParent(this);
```

По закрытию главного окна программы (this обозначает указатель на главное окно) я могу быть уверен в том, что будет вызван оператор delete для данных по адресу указателя data?

Comment: Без атрибута `WA_DeleteOnClose` объект окна при закрытии не удаляется. При удалении `QObject`-а удаляются все его дочерние объекты. Вы в любом случае можете сделать дебажный вывод в деструкторе и посмотреть.

Comment: Сборки мусора в QT нет. Вызывая `setParent` владение указателем передается родительскому объекту.

Comment: imho обычно в функции main есть явный деструктор главного окна, если это так, то да можете

Comment: @user7860670, меня интересует в таком случае реализация RAII, если вы о *владении*

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите гарантировать удаление, то используйте умные указатели, как shared_ptr к примеру.

*shared_ptr - Этот умный указатель разрешает объекту иметь несколько владельцев, а когда все владельцы уничтожаются, уничтожается и объект. Такое поведение достигается за счёт наличия специального счётчика ссылок внутри std::shared_ptr. Каждый раз, когда такой указатель копируется, счётчик инкрементируется, а когда один из указателей уничтожается – декрементируется. В момент, когда счётчик достигает нуля, объект уничтожается.*

**Цитата с сайта proglib.io - "https://proglib.io/p/umnye-ukazateli-v-c-2021-08-26";**

```
void CustomRectItem::fkn_problems()
{
    shared_ptr<QGraphicsRectItem>data = make_shared<QGraphicsRectItem>();
    data->setParentItem(this);
}
```

Вы в Qt, поэтому лучше использовать Qt-шные библиотеки:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qshareddatapointer.html

Comment: Без пояснения про `setParent` ответ выглядит странно.